# Match SQL queries using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I want to match the same type of SQL queries which might have different parameters. For example

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE Name = 'Bearing Ball' and ProductNumber = 'BA-8327'
```

and

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE Name = 'Cycle' and ProductNumber = 'CY-1234'
```

are the the same type of queries with different parameters. Basically anything can replace 'Bearing Ball' and 'BA-8327' in the first example. The parameters can be strings or number or dates with or without white space. I tried the following expression :

```
var result = new Regex("SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = '*' and ProductNumber = '*'").IsMatch(query)
```

it's not working as expected. Please give me a solution.

Comment: "Not working as expected" is not enough information. Please provide what you `expect` to happen and what `happened`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is not a wildcard.  I replaced it with `('([^']|'')*'|\d+)` which matches a single-quoted string that contains characters other than `'` or sequential `''` (escaped single quote) 0 or more times.  Alternatively, it matches a 1 or more sequential digits.

There was a previous post (which was deleted) that mentioned escaping the `.` wildcard.  It is good advice and I've updated my answer to reflect that as well.

```
var result = new Regex(@"SELECT Name FROM Production\.Product WHERE Name = ('([^']|'')*'|\d+) and ProductNumber = ('([^']|'')*'|\d+)").IsMatch(query);
```

Comment: Your answers is working for queries which doesn't have numbers, for example "SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = 'Bearing Ball' and ProductNumber = 1" in this query I have a integer in the where clause, so it's not working for that. How to modify '([^']|'')+' to find string inside single quotes also integers without quotes.

Comment: @Deepan - Based on your clarification, I've updated my regex to capture integers in addition to strings.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a system to turn all the important data into dynamic entities after the regex parsing. That way you can determine if the operations are the same. Otherwise you can look at the pattern and add things to yours to read the data properly such as using `\x27([^\x27]+)\x27` to match `'Bearing Ball'` which speaks to the needs of your pattern.

---

```
string pattern = @"
^                     # Start of the line
select\s              # Anything not in brackets do not capture.
(?<What>[^\s]+)       # Capture a name most likely
\sfrom\s
(?<Table>[^\s]+)      # Capture Table name
\swhere\s
\1                    # Name(?) the what, must be used again
\s*=\s*
\x27                  # \x27 is a single quote '
(?<Name>[^\x27]+)     # Read up to the next quote for the what.
\x27
\s+and\s+ProductNumber\s*=\s*
\x27
(?<ProdNumber>[^\x27]+)  # Read up to the next quote for the product number.
";

string data = @"
SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = 'Bearing Ball' and ProductNumber = 'BA-8327'
SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = 'Cycle' and ProductNumber = 'CY-1234'
";

// IgnorePatternWhitespace lets us space out and comment the pattern code only. Does not affect regex processing.
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mat => new
     {
        Table = mat.Groups["Table"].Value,
        What = mat.Groups["What"].Value,
        Name  = mat.Groups["Name"].Value,
        ProductNumber = mat.Groups["ProdNumber"].Value
     });
```

**Result of 2 Dynamic Entities**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Arvind Shyamsundar's blog posting over at MSDN, this does exactly what you're looking for and can be adapted for more. It uses the ScriptDom classes, Microsoft's own T-SQL parser and generator code, which seems like a much better approach than trying to parse a complicated language like T-SQL yourself. [Normalizing T-SQL text using the transactsql scriptdom classes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2014/01/02/normalizing-t-sql-text-part-2-using-the-transactsql-scriptdom-classes/)

Be ware that a set of classes named ScriptDom lives in 2 different namespaces. The one you should be using is shipped with SQL Server as of SQL Server 2012 and has a name space of Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom. The one with name space Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom is an older, less potent version that used to be shipped with Visual Studio. You should no longer use the latter one in any new projects.